# longtable makes scrartcl collide with footer after float

Tags: longtable, scrartcl

It seems like having a longtable on the same page as a float that has moved there causes the length calculation to bail out so that the text covers the footer. MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe} % For dummy figures
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor} % To visualize footer better

% Set up footer
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ifoot{\color{red}aaa}
\ofoot{\color{red}bbb}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\lipsum[1-3]    
\begin{figure} % Figure that will float to next page
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
\section{B}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{longtable}{|c|}
\hline
Table\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\section{B}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Note the red (for clarity) footer text. Same with both latex and pdflatex. No need to define your own footer, but was clearer that way. Will overwrite page number if no special footer defined.

[image: Text covering footer]

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: If you make your `longtable` long enough so that it yctually triggers a mid-table page break, the contents do not overflow into the footer.

Comment: it is a known bug, and you need the new longtable from here https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/tree/longtable4.14 then it will work again.

Comment: @leandriis unfortunately not. I could have shown such an example as well, but it seems to be the pure existence of longtable that causes it.